# Problem using http GET request in flutter

Tags: http, flutter

So I got a template of a Flutter app that retrieves all its data from a website using HTTP get requests.

I have the following method that gets the list of resturaunts:

```
 Future<Stream<Restaurant>> getNearRestaurants(LocationData myLocation, LocationData areaLocation) async {
  String _nearParams = '';
  String _orderLimitParam = '';
  if (myLocation != null && areaLocation != null) {
    _orderLimitParam = 'orderBy=area&limit=5';
    _nearParams = '&myLon=${myLocation.longitude}&myLat=${myLocation.latitude}&areaLon=${areaLocation.longitude}&areaLat=${areaLocation.latitude}';
  }
  final String url = '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}restaurants?$_nearParams&$_orderLimitParam';
  final client = new http.Client();
  final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url)));

  return streamedRest.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).map((data) => Helper.getData(data)).expand((data) => (data as List)).map((data) {
    return Restaurant.fromJSON(data);
  });
}
```

However when I swap the template's **url** variable for my own website, the app gets stuck since it cannot retrieve the same information from my website.

What could I be missing? Is the problem in the flutter code or the website?

**Update 1:**

I surrounded it with a try/catch block and it gave me a **"bad certificate exception."**. This might be because my website does not have a SSL certificate, so I added an exception to the HttpClient for my self-certified website:

```
  bool _certificateCheck(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) =>
  host == '<domain>'; 

  HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient()..badCertificateCallback = (_certificateCheck);
  HttpClientRequest request = await client2.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = await request.close(); // sends the request
  // transforms and prints the response
  response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen(print);
```

This code showed a **Error 404: Not found** on the page that I need to get my JSON data from.

I also installed postman and checked my website with the GET statement for the same list of restaurants I try to retrieve in the flutter code posted above and see this:
[Postman GET screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjA9b.png)

**Update 2:**

So I configured SSL on my website and the problem still persists. I tried testing the GET request via postman and it returns a error 404 page as well. I have tried going through my server files and laravel logs and nothing did the trick.

Its as if my website cannot route to the specific pages in my API folder. BUt they are all defined in api.php.

Comment: Could you try to surround the parts inside of the method with a try {} catch(e){} and take a look if an error occurs?

Comment: To find out whether the problem is in the Flutter code or website, make the GET request via Postman. See the result. If you get correct result then it means the problem is in the code otherwise its in the website. In case the problem is in the code, try to print the strings like  url, _nearParams since they have lot of variables in it. Check whether they are set as expected.

Comment: I have posted updates to both proposed solutions.